# What is an alternative to comparing two string with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to compare two strings, which has a different delimiter in between.

Example

```
String s1 = "ZZ E5 - Pirates of carribean";
String s2 = "ZZ E5 : Pirates of carribean";
```

I want to compare if two strings are equal.

I've tried using regex in Java to solve this,

```
        String pattern = "(.*)[:-](.*)";
        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher m = r.matcher(s1);
        Matcher m1 = r.matcher(s2);

        if (m1.find()&&m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(1));
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m1.group(2));

            System.out.println(m.group(1).contentEquals(m1.group(1)));
            System.out.println(m.group(2).contentEquals(m1.group(2)));
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH");
        }
```

Is this a good approach or we can do this in some other efficient way ?

Comment: In regex you have to compile it 1 time and use it as many time as you want. I prefer regex over string methods. But regex are devil too. so if performance is not as issue use string methods. or take extra precaution while using regex.

Comment: Here is an idea [`s1.replaceAll("[-:]", "#").equals(s2.replaceAll("[-:]", "#"));`](http://www.ideone.com/vgSiCh)

Comment: I wonder what the expectation would be when the movie has a title like `"Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could convert both strings to a *canonical form* by choosing one of the delimiters as *canonical*, for example:

```
String s1 = "ZZ E5 - Pirates of carribean";
String s2 = "ZZ E5 : Pirates of carribean";

String canonicalS1 = s1.replaceAll("-", ":");
String canonicalS2 = s2.replaceAll("-", ":");

System.out.println(canonicalS1.equals(canonicalS2));
```

**Output**

```
true
```

Note that this solution expects that the delimiters appear only one time, or for that matter that the delimiters are interchangeable.

Comment: Since you are not using a regex you could also just use `String.replace()`.  And that will replace all of them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.split()` and the regex OR operator (if you know all possible delimiters already) and compare the arrays.

```
import java.utils.Arrays;

String pattern = "-|:";
if (Arrays.equals(s1.split(pattern), (s2.split(pattern)))) {
    System.out.println("Match");
} else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

edited to use `Arrays.equals`

Comment: `split` returns an array, and arrays don't implement `equals`, so that will always be false.

Comment: my bad, meant to use `Arrays.equals()`. updated my answer